# CSS for fixed image to overlap menu

Tags: css, image, overlap

I have this image:

[image: triangle]

Here is the website http://maximearchambault.com

You have the menu at the left and the content at the right.

What I would like to do is to put the triangle image next to the menu overlapping the content so it look like part of the menu.

Here a example: http://www.shockblast.net/marla-singer-photography/

When you scroll down you will see an eye appear and everything goes under it. The eye doesn't move.

So I want my image aligned left overlapping the content in the right column.

Here is my default/style.css

```
*/

 body {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    /* font-weight: 300; */
}

/* link scheme */
/* you can customize links further down the page too */
a:link { text-decoration: none; color: #000; }
a:active { text-decoration: none; color: #00cc00; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #999; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
a img { border: none; }

/* general styles */
small { font-size: 9px; }
code { font-family: monospace; }
blockquote { padding-left: 9px; }

/* headings */
h1 { font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 1em; font-weight: bold; }
h2 { font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 1em; font-weight: bold; }
h3 { font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 1em; }
h4 { font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 1em; }

/* paragraph width */
#index p { margin-bottom: 1em; }
#exhibit p, code, blockquote { width: 450px; margin-bottom: 1em; /* line-height: 1.3em; */ }

/* highlighter style - maybe you want to change colors? */
.highlight { background: #ccff00; color: #000; }

/* never adjust the margin or padding here unless you seriously know what you are doing */
/* think #index .container and #exhibit .container for only padding adjustments */
#index { width: 215px; background: #F2F2F2; /* line-height: 1.3em; */ }
#exhibit { margin: 0 0 0 215px; }

/* styling the index */
#index ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; }
#index ul.section { margin-bottom: 1em; }
#index ul.subsection {  }

/* the follow rules for index are not required */
/* they are mostly for complex customization */
/* for tag display */
#index ul#all_tags { list-style-type: none; margin-bottom: 1em; }
#index ul#all_tags li { display: inline; margin-right: 3px; }
#index ul#all_tags li a {  }

/* active section title */
#index span.active_section_title,
#index span.active_section_title a { font-weight: bold; }

/* active exhibit title parts */
li.active a:link, li a.active, li.active a:hover, li a.active, li.active a:active, li a.active, 
li.active a:visited, li a.active, li span.active, #index ul.section li.active a:link, 
#index ul.section li.active a:hover, #index ul.section li.active a:active, #index ul.section li.active a:visited
{ font-weight: bold; }

/* additional #index options */
#index ul li .password a { /* background: url(../img/locked.gif) right center no-repeat; padding-right: 18px; */ }

/* the "new" indicator */
#index ul li sup { color: #0c0; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 8px; vertical-align: top; }
/* end styling for index */

/* links styles only for the #index region */
#index a:link {  } 
#index a:hover {  } 
#index a:active {  } 
#index a:visted {  }

/* links styles only for the #exhibit region */
#exhibit a:link {  } 
#exhibit a:hover {  } 
#exhibit a:active {  } 
#exhibit a:visted {  } 

/* this is where you adjust your paddings for #index and #exhibit together */
.container { padding: 27px 9px 25px 27px; }

/* this is where you pad them separately */
#index .container {  }
#exhibit .container {  }
```

Comment: Someone please edit to make it understandable.

Comment: @SVS Edits should be visible upon peer review :)

Answer (score 1):

Put these properties on the element you want fixed:

```
  .fixedElement
  {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
  }
```

This way it will be always fixed on the top left. even after scrolling

Comment: Thank for the code, but i am a beginner. First i will need the code to place the image and where to past the code

Comment: This css class is for any element to be put on the top left of a page and stay there...  you will need to add an image with something like this: <img src="/img/1.jpg" class="fixedElement" alt="" /> you can put it anywhere on the page